# Getting the actual Form values when using tivo/tview GoLang library

Tags: user-interface, go, command-line-interface

It's not at all obvious to me how to get the value the user inputs for the Name input field, in below simple snippet.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/rivo/tview"
)

func main() {

    app := tview.NewApplication()
    form := tview.NewForm()
    form.SetTitle(" My Form ")
    form.AddInputField("Name", "", 20, nil, nil)
    form.AddButton("OK", func() { app.Stop() })
    if err := app.SetRoot(form, true).SetFocus(form).Run(); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s\n", form.GetFormItem(0))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The form has only two items, one inputfield, one button.

the part

```
app.SetRoot(form, true).SetFocus(form).Run()
```

runs the form. Klicking the button continues the execution afterwards by stopping the app-window.

The inputfield `'Name'` is put into the form first. It is accessed by `form.GetFormItem(0)` (by it's index).

See https://github.com/rivo/tview/blob/master/form.go  row 244ff

> ```
> // GetFormItem returns the form element at the given position, starting with  
> // index 0. Elements are referenced in the order they were added. Buttons are  
> // not included.  
> func (f *Form) GetFormItem(index int) FormItem {
>   return f.items[index]
> ```

Comment: Thanks @patrick-artner, but the structure of the `form.GetFormItem(0)` object is what's not clear. How do print *only* the `Name` value of that object?

Comment: https://github.com/rivo/tview/blob/master/inputfield.go - `GetText()` seems to be what you need then. You might need to cast the return of `GetFormIndex(0)` to `InputField(form.GetFormIndex(0))` as it returns the Interfacetype 'type FormItem interface' (defined in top of form.go)

Comment: Yeah, `fmt.Printf("%s\n", form.GetFormItem(0).(*tview.InputField).GetText() )` does the trick. Thanks, Patrick!

Comment: These days you can now use form.GetFormItemByLabel(label), so you don't have to rely on indices